# Need help translating a NETLOGO 4.1 model to 6.0.1 (Couldn't find corresponding reader for BUTTON)

Tags: netlogo

I am getting an error message when I open a Netlogo 4.1 model in Netlogo 6.0.1.  It seems to be having problems with graphical user interface elements like buttons:

[image: Error message]

After clicking OK, I get a blank screen:

[image]

Here is what the model looks like in Netlogo 4.1 (this shows what should be displayed:

[image]

I looked in the [transition guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html), but didn't find any relevant information.  I am sure that I can put up Netlogo 4.1 and Netlogo 6.0.1 side by side, copy/paste the code (with updates for the new edition) over from Netlogo 4.1 to Netlogo 6.0.1, and then recreate the GUI components in Netlogo 6.0.1.  But, I am wondering if there isn't a more automated way?  The website I got the model from is [Netlogo Bag of Tricks](http://backspaces.net/wiki/NetLogo_Bag_of_Tricks).

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442640/netlogo-transition-backwards-compatibility/42462593#42462593) for one potential way to automate (most of) your upgrades.It's not exactly pretty, but it did work for the majority of the models I tested.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening it in [NetLogo 5.3.1](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.3.1/) first. If that auto-conversion works, save the model, then open in 6.0.1.